# Send large string to controller using ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC application, in which I need to send data stored in sessionStorage to a Controller. This storage has a key-value pair, in which the key is 'confirmed'. The value is an array with numbers, like [1,2,3,4,5].

I need to send this array to my controller, and everything works fine, except when this array is too long. I've tried changing the config with:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000000" />
 </appSettings>
```

and

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>  
         <webServices>                                                   
             <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />                 
         </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

but nothing seems to work. It only works fine when the array is not so long.
Here's my code:

**Script:**

```
$(".enviar").click(function () {
        getSelectedItems();

        var seleccion = sessionStorage.confirmed;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            type: "POST",
            //data: { confirm: JSON.stringify(seleccion) },
            data: JSON.stringify({ confirm: seleccion }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (returndata) {
                window.location = "@Url.Action("SomeAction","Controller")";
            },
            error: function (returndata) {
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("AnotherAction","Controller")";
            }
        });

        //sessionStorage.clear();
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string confirm)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(confirm))
        {
            confirm = confirm.Substring(1, confirm.Length - 2);
            var confirmadas = confirm.Split(',');

            foreach (var id in confirmadas)
            {
                //change things in DB
            }

            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("SomeAction", "Controller") });

        }
        return Json(new { ok = false, newurl = Url.Action("SomeAction", "Controller") });
    }
```

Please help, I've tried nearly everything and it works sometimes, but other times it doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.join the array to a string :

```
var str=seleccion .join(",");
```

2.just pass it to the data object

```
data: { confirm: str}
```